# Build a circuit taking a starting box and trying to search, horizontally and vertically, for other boxes that are not None within a matrix

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, matrix

```py
from random import shuffle


matrix_aux_with_num_decompositions = [
    [None,  'b', None,  100,  100,   -3],
    [None, None,  200,  'a', None,  100],
    [ 100,  200, None, None, None, None],
]

matrix_aux_with_num_decompositions_aux = [
    [     -1, 'asign',      -3, 'asign', 'asign',      -3],
    [      5,       4, 'asign', 'asign',      -2, 'asign'],
    ['asign', 'asign',      -9,      -3,      -1,      -5],
]

#Possible coordinates of lockers that will function as starting points for the possible circuit
#Note that they are the coordinates of the only positive values within the matrix called matrix_aux_with_num_decompositions_aux
coords_posibles_elementos_de_partida = [ [1, 0], [1, 1] ]
#optionally we can exchange the starting points to analyze them randomly
shuffle(coords_posibles_elementos_de_partida)
```

Try each of the boxes (given of the form [row, column]) in the list called `coords_posibles_elementos_de_partida` , until I get one that allows me to build a closed circuit, following the rule that can only extract data **horizontally** and **vertically**, and that must end where it started, that is, in the number of coordinates chosen from `coords_posibles_elementos_de_partida`
The rest of the boxes, we will call them **vertices**, and they must be box values that are different from `None` and that are within the part of the matrix `matrix_aux_with_num_decompositions`

The circuits **cannot have diagonal connections**, and they must be closed, for example if it starts at [1, 0], a circuit that loops through values within `matrix_aux_with_num_decompositions` that are different from `None` and leaving them as vertices.

The way to express the output list would be:

`[[start_point_row, start_point_col], [1_vertex_row, 1_vertex_col], ..., [i_vertex_row, i_vertex_col]]`

This would be a list with a possible correct list (correct output) in which the vertices are listed in an orderly manner, starting from the starting point (and closing, because it closes at the beginning).

```py
circuit_list = [[1, 0], [1, 3], [0, 3], [0, 1], [2, 1], [2,0] ]
```

, and after the last vertex, in this case `[2, 0]`, returns to the beginning `[1, 0]` , because circuits are closed loops.

This is my code, but its logic does not work correctly

```py
def is_valid_move(matrix, visited, row, col):
    # Check if the move is within the matrix boundaries and the cell is not visited
    return 0 <= row < len(matrix) and 0 <= col < len(matrix[0]) and not visited[row][col] and matrix[row][col] is not None

#Depth-First Search is a graph traversal algorithm used to explore nodes and edges of a graph
def dfs(matrix, visited, row, col, start_row, start_col, path):
    # Define the possible moves: up, down, left, right
    moves = [(-1, 0), (1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1)]

    # Mark the current cell as visited
    visited[row][col] = True

    # Append the current cell to the path
    path.append([row, col])

    # If the current cell is the starting cell and all cells are visited, return the path
    if row == start_row and col == start_col and all(all(cell for cell in row) for row in visited):
        return path

    # Explore all possible moves
    for move in moves:
        new_row, new_col = row + move[0], col + move[1]
        if is_valid_move(matrix, visited, new_row, new_col):
            result = dfs(matrix, visited, new_row, new_col, start_row, start_col, path)
            if result:
                return result

    # If no valid moves left, backtrack
    visited[row][col] = False
    path.pop()
    return None
```

```py
def find_circuit(matrix, start_coords):
    for start_coord in start_coords:
        start_row, start_col = start_coord
        visited = [[False for _ in range(len(matrix[0]))] for _ in range(len(matrix))]
        path = []

        circuit = dfs(matrix, visited, start_row, start_col, start_row, start_col, path)

        if circuit:
            return circuit

    return None
```

```py
# Find a possible closed loop
circuit = find_circuit(matrix_aux_with_num_decompositions, coords_posibles_elementos_de_partida)

# Print Circuit Vertex List
if circuit:
    print("Circuit found: ")
    print(circuit)
else:
    print("No closed circuit found.")
```

But unfortunately my code fails since it incorrectly indicates that there is no possible circuit, but that is not true, since in the following image we can see that it is possible to draw at least one circuit.

[image: here the image]

Here a image with some examples about possible and not possible circuits:

[image: possible and not possible circuits]

Comment: Are all possible circuits equally desirable, or do they have different costs?

Comment: The objective is to be able to build a closed circuit (without using diagonals), the vertices have to be boxes that do not contain a None. As seen in the image, it is not necessary for the circuit to be rectangular, but there cannot be diagonal unions between vertices.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. If there are two different solutions that satisfy those constraints, are they always equally desirable?

Comment: Is `[[1, 0], [1, 3] [1, 0]]` a solution? If not, why not?

Comment: @Reinderien Not, it is not a solution because it must be a circuit, in that case it would be a straight line, it goes back and forth on itself, but a circuit has a starting point, it has a route and then it returns to that starting point.

Comment: ...a straight line also has a starting point, a route and then a return to the starting point. You're going to need to be more specific.

Comment: @Reinderien The point is in the word "circuit", for example a straight line cannot be a circuit, electrical circuits have to be closed loops, racing car circuits cannot be a straight line either, but must be closed loops. **A straight line cannot be a circuit because a circuit implies the existence of a closed path**

Comment: Also keep in mind that if the straight line is not a circuit, then there must be more than 3 vertices to form the circuit, but since it is impossible to form a circuit of 3 vertices without diagonals, then we can be sure that **the minimum number of vertices selectable to form a circuit must be 4 vertices**

Comment: A straight line is also a closed path. I think what you're dancing around is that your solution network traversal cannot have any fully overlapping edges.

Comment: @Reinderien If you want to analyze it that way it could also work, the circuit should not have vertex boxes that overlap, I think the best way to look at it is as an electric circuit or a racing circuit, for a unidirectional circuit to flow it should not go back and forth itself. I also emphasize that the circuit must be built respecting the rule that there are at least 4 vertices (where one of the vertices is the starting point itself).

Answer (score 1):

It's not generally worth doing this yourself; use NetworkX instead:

```py
import networkx
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

matrix = [
    [None,  'b', None,  100,  100,   -3],
    [None, None,  200,  'a', None,  100],
    [ 100,  200, None, None, None, None],
]
m = len(matrix)
n = len(matrix[0])

graph = networkx.Graph()

for i, row in enumerate(matrix):
    graph.update(
        networkx.complete_graph([
            (i, j)
            for j, elm in enumerate(row)
            if elm is not None
        ])
    )
for j in range(n):
    graph.update(
        networkx.complete_graph([
            (i, j)
            for i, row in enumerate(matrix)
            if row[j] is not None
        ])
    )

print(networkx.find_cycle(graph))

networkx.draw(graph, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

```
[((0, 1), (0, 3)), ((0, 3), (0, 4)), ((0, 4), (0, 1))]
```

[image: graph graph]

Depending on your (still somewhat nebulous) "no straight line" constraint, you can choose from any of the possible cycles:

```py
for cycle in networkx.simple_cycles(graph):
    if len({
        i for i, j in cycle
    }) > 1 and len({
        j for i, j in cycle
    }) > 1:
        print(cycle)
```

```
[(0, 1), (0, 3), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 5), (0, 5)]
[(0, 1), (0, 3), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 5), (0, 5), (0, 4)]
[(0, 1), (0, 3), (1, 3), (1, 5), (0, 5)]
[(0, 1), (0, 3), (1, 3), (1, 5), (0, 5), (0, 4)]
[(0, 1), (0, 4), (0, 3), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 5), (0, 5)]
[(0, 1), (0, 4), (0, 3), (1, 3), (1, 5), (0, 5)]
[(0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (1, 5), (1, 2), (1, 3)]
[(0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (1, 5), (1, 3)]
[(0, 3), (0, 5), (1, 5), (1, 2), (1, 3)]
[(0, 3), (0, 5), (1, 5), (1, 3)]
```

Comment: Sorry, this code give me that **error**:   ```File "F:\backup\backup\python\transport_problems\test.py", line 72, in <module>
    networkx.draw(graph, with_labels=True)
  File "C:\Users\PC0\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_pylab.py", line 113, in draw
    if cf._axstack() is None:
TypeError: '_AxesStack' object is not callable```

Comment: Update your packages or comment out the draw call

Comment: Why is the solution given as a tuple of subtuples? [((0, 1), (0, 3)), ((0, 3), (0, 4)), ((0, 4), (0, 1))] , instead of being a list of the coordinates of the vertices like this [[1, 0], [1, 3], [0, 3], [0, 1], [2, 1], [2,0] ] ?

Comment: Because those are edge definitions with terminal nodes. Read the documentation for `find_cycle` here: https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.find_cycle.html#networkx.algorithms.cycles.find_cycle

Comment: I have added at the end of my question some examples of what shapes the circuits could have and what shapes they could not have.

Comment: Fine I guess? Your diagrams don't include a multi-node line, so I'll just have to assume that that's also disallowed. Filter the cycles by the number of unique coordinates in each node dimension.

Comment: As they are closed circuits with only one path, there cannot be branches, that is, one node connects with another node, that is, circuits can only be created in series but never in parallel. This code give me that wrong output  [((0, 1), (0, 3)), ((0, 3), (0, 4)), ((0, 4), (0, 1))]

Comment: Have you read the answer?

Comment: Yes, but this code part `for cycle in networkx.simple_cycles(graph):` give me that error ```for cycle in networkx.simple_cycles(graph):
  File "utils\decorators.py", line 845, in func
    return argmap._lazy_compile(__wrapper)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<class 'networkx.utils.decorators.argmap'> compilation 12", line 3, in argmap_simple_cycles_9
  File "\utils\decorators.py", line 88, in _not_implemented_for
    raise nx.NetworkXNotImplemented(errmsg)
networkx.exception.NetworkXNotImplemented: not implemented for undirected type```

Comment: That's a you-problem. The code as shown with a modern environment does not encounter that error.